# What happens when index merged?

Tags: indexing, sphinx

what `SRCINDEX` index doing when execute the following command
what change in the `SRCINDEX` index's content

```
indexer --merge DSTINDEX SRCINDEX [--rotate]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SRCINDEX` is only READ. And its data added to `DSTINDEX`. It is not changed.

Comment: and data in DSTINDEX will be overwritten by SRCINDEX data if duplicate document id http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#index-merging

Answer (score 0):

This is example of Index Merging.  It is used to append the delta index to the main index.

The DSTINDEX is main index and SRCINDEX is delta. It is actually merging the documents of SRCINDEX to DSTINDEX. It is used when we don’t want to re-index the documents which are already indexed. I think this is easiest explanation of your question.

I hope this would be helpful for you.

Thanks